# Arrange segments in rows without overlapping

Tags: algorithm

There is a set of segments `{(a_i,b_i) with i = 1, ..., n}` with `0 <= a_i < b_i <= 1` that has to be arranged on N lines `[0,1]` without overlap.

For example, if a set can consist of `{(0.35,0.41), (0.40,0.43), (0.47,0.88)}` and `N >= 2`, one can arrange the segments without overlaps. With `N = 1` that's not possible, because the first and the second segment overlap.

Without any constraint on which line a segment must be placed on, one possible algorithm is the following: sort the segments according to their starting point `a_i` and then place them one after the other on one of the `N` lines. If it's not possible to place the segment `a_i` on any of the lines without overlapping with any of the already placed segments, it means there's no solution.

What if some of the segments have constraints on the line they have to be placed on? For example, the segment `(a_2,b_2)` may be placed only on the 3rd line, and one writes it as `(a_2,b_2;3)`.

One possible situation is the following: `{(0.45,0.56;-), (0.48,0.67;-), (0.66,0.70;2), (0.68,0.71;-)}` and `N = 2`.
If one places the first segment on the first line, the second segment must go on the second line and the third segment can not fulfil the constraint. On the contrary, if the first segment is placed on the second line, the second segment goes on the first line, the third on the second line fulfilling the constraint and the last one on the first line.

*What I've tried*

1. Try every combination that fulfils the constraints. In the last example `{1,2}x{1,2}x{2}x{1,2}` After the first one without any overlap, the program returns the combination, which is a solution of the problem. Of course it works, of course it's slow.
2. Draw a line `[0,1]` marked with points that are boundaries of at least one segment. Build a list `I` of intervals made of two consecutive points. For each element of `I` take the list `S` of segments that covers it. For each subset `S'` of `S` build the set `A'` equal to the union of the line numbers they are allowed on. For example for `S' = {(0.5,0.6;1,2), (0.4,0.7;2)}`, `A' = {1, 2}`. If the cardinality of `A'` is smaller than the cardinality of `S'`, there's no solution. Unfortunately, the opposite is not always true.
3. Scan every interval in point `2.` and remove the lines a segment can not be placed on, according to the constraints on other segments. For example, if a segment is constrained on line 2, this is not an option for any other segment that has an intersection with it. Keep scanning the interval list until no more reductions are possible. Then use the basic algorithm in `1.` with this subset of possible combinations.
4. Draw a square matrix `A` of size `n` (`n` be the number of segments). `a_ij` equals `1` if they overlap, `0` if they don't. Only specific operations on the matrix are allowed according to whether segments have constraints or not (if two rows are swapped, the same columns has to be swapped, segments with constraints can not be swapped arbitrarily). If one can obtain a matrix that has a number of diagonal blocks `<= N` that are the identity matrix, there's the solution. Not sure if it's a viable option, nor if it makes sense.
5. Consider `I`, `S`, `S'` and `A'` as defined in `2.`. If the cardinality of `A'` is smaller than the cardinality of `S'`, abort (no solution). If the cardinality of `A'` is equal to the cardinality of `S'`, remove the line numbers of `A'` from the segments that intersect *every* element of `S'`.

   Keep scanning `I` until no reduction is possible any more. **Is it true that if the program hasn't aborted up to this point, one is left with all the possible solutions to the problem?** (Yes, but not only those)

   For example, `N = 3`, `S = {(0.5,0.6;1,2), (0.4,0.7;2), (0.5,0.6;1,2,3)}`. One of the subset is `S' = {(0.5,0.6;1,2), (0.4,0.7;2)}` for which one has `A' = {1,2}`. Cardinality of `S'` equals cardinality of `A'`, therefore one has to remove `{1,2}` from the lines allowed for every segment not in `S'`. One obtains `S = {(0.5,0.6;1,2), (0.4,0.7;2), (0.5,0.6;3)}`. Doing the same with `S' = {(0.4,0.7;2)}`, `2` is removed from the first segment and one obtains `S = {(0.5,0.6;1), (0.4,0.7;2), (0.5,0.6;3)}`, which is the (single possible) solution.

   Counterexample: for `N = 2` and `{(0.5,0.6;-), (0.55,0.7;-), (0.65,0.8;-)}`, not every combination from `{1,2}x{1,2}x{1,2}` is a solution. The reason is related to the symmetry of the (true) solutions. If after each complete run of the algorithm, one fixes one of the segment on one of its allowed lines (thus breaking the symmetry) and rerun the algorithm, one gets a solution for this proposed set.

   **Can one this way always get a solution (when it exists) or the program aborts when it doesn't?**
6. If `5.` is correct, is it possible to calculate the solution for `n` segments from the solution for `n-1` segments?

*Obeservations (from the comments and from me)*

The constraints enforcing that some segments go on some specific lines can be relaxed quite a bit, since after finishing a solution you're completely free to renumber the lines without changing whether the segments on a *single line* overlap or not. So, e.g., if two segments are supposed to be on line 5, all this really means is that they have to be on the *same line*; and if one segment is supposed to be on line 3 and another one on line 7, all this really means is that they have to be on *different lines*.

If any point `x` is not covered by any segment, the problem can be split in 2 problems having lines `[0,x]` and `[x,1]` long and two sets of distinct segments. Therefore one has to assume that every point in `[0,1]` is covered by at least one segment.

Comment: First observation: The constraints enforcing that some segments go on some specific lines can be relaxed quite a bit, since after finishing a solution you're completely free to renumber the lines without changing whether the segments *on a single line* overlap or not.  So, e.g., if two segments are supposed to be on line 5, all this really means is that they have to be on *the same* line; and if one segment is supposed to be on line 3 and another one on line 7, all this really means is that they have to be on *different* lines.

Comment: I have a more substantial answer, but before I give it, I'd like to see some evidence that this isn't a homework question that you're trying to solve without any of your own effort (possible evidence: what ideas you've tried so far), or a question from an active programming competition (possible evidence: a link to an *inactive* programming competition webpage with this question).

Comment: I don't have any idea where to start from to look for an active or inactive program competition and I'm not going to scan my ID card to show that I'm too old for homework, so I'll tell you what I've tried over the last few days.

Comment: I've edited the question with some things I've tried. I see in my notes I have 2 more, but I need to decipher them because I can't understand what I did. I will update the question as soon as I can recall what I wrote down.

Comment: Thanks, I'll respond tomorrow.

Comment: It would be useful to have a rough idea of the numbers: How big does N get?  How many segments?  How many other segments does a typical segment intersect with?  How many constrained segments are there?  Also are most endpoints distinct, or is it the case that many segments share one or both endpoints with others?  I haven't been able to prove NP-hardness, but any exact algorithm will probably need to be exponential in at least some of these parameters, so hopefully some of them are usually small.

Comment: For my specific case `N ~ 10-15`, the segments are ~ `0.03-0.1` long, I would say hardly more than `50-80`. Most endpoints are distinct. I think one can imagine a packed situation with lot of segments or a sparse situation. I guess that for my specific needs a slow algorithm would be fine, but then I started to be interested on the problem per se.

Comment: Regarding 5, please confirm you meant to write "If the cardinality of a subset is **bigger** than the number of the lines they are allowed on, abort (no solution). If the cardinality of the subset is equal to the number of the lines they are allowed on, remove these line numbers from the available options of the other segments that **intersect with any of the segments that** cover this interval."  I believe that doing this never eliminates a valid solution.  It might shrink the problem a lot, or not at all.

Comment: What fraction of the segments are usually constrained to a particular line?  If this is near 0% or 100%, the problem gets easier.

Comment: I rephrased point 2. and 5., incorporating your corrections. Please let me know whether it's clearer or not. The percentage of segment constrained varies equally from 0 to 100.

Comment: "remove the line numbers of `A'` from the segments that are not in `S'`" -- do you mean "from the segments that are in `S` but not in `S'`"?  That would be correct.  Also my earlier claim that these lines can be removed from the allowed-lines set of any other segment that overlaps any of the segments in S' is wrong -- they can, however, also be removed from the allowed-lines set of any other segment that overlaps *every* segment in S'.

Comment: Yes I meant from `S'` that are not in `S`. I corrected it with "any other segment that overlaps *every* segment" as you suggested.

Comment: Now, I can't prove that one with `5.` gets a solution when it exists. Were it the case, should one obtain the solution for `n-1` segments (without the last step to break the symmetry) and then add the `nth`?

Comment: Have you considered graph theory? It sounds like a graph coloring problem with additional restrictions on the possible colors. The original problem has an optimal polynomial-time algorithm, just like the one you describe first. Maybe it won't be too hard to adapt? I doubt it, but it's still worth a try. You'll also find a ton of writings about variants of graph coloring. Hours of fun to find your particular problem ;)

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring if so, I'll have a look on my book

Comment: Yes, here nodes will be intervals, and edges represent overlapping intervals. Your initial classical variant has a nice polynomial solution, which is stated on that page: *for special cases of chordal graphs such as interval graphs, the greedy coloring algorithm can be used to find optimal colorings in polynomial time, by choosing the vertex ordering to be the reverse of a perfect elimination ordering for the graph.* Once you have the PEO, you can pre-color your constrained nodes and then apply the first-color-available routine. Just doing that will lead to a solution, although not optimal.

Comment: Thanks! I think this problem has already a name: it's called "Precoloring extension on interval graphs"

Comment: Great! Did you find that on the book you mentioned? It looks like an efficient resource. And good for you, I also see that your particular needs seem to model to a polynomially solvable problem.

Comment: No, I didn't even get to the book (actually I did, but then I forgot that I haven't found anything useful. It's just an introduction to algorithms) :). It's been a mix of Wikipedia and Google. I got the keyword "List coloring" from the "Other colorings" on the first Wikipedia link, and the keyword "Interval graph" from your last comment. Those led me to "Precoloring extension". "Precoloring extension" + "Interval graph" gave me this: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9290646W

Comment: Cormen et al. / Introduction to Algorithms is the book I've looked into, but it only briefly mentions graph coloring and only one case

Comment: It turns out that your problem is actually NP-hard, as it's a special case of the "k-track assignment problem", which is NP-hard (see p. 2 of "The k-track assignment problem", Brucker and Nordmann 1994).  Don't have time to go into much more detail now, other than to say that this is certainly a surprise, as it's very "close" to being a problem that can be solved in O(n log n) time!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this problem can be translated to [Vertex Coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring):

Let every segment be a vertex in a undirected graph. Two vertices will have an edge between them iff the corresponding segments overlap. Thus we need to assign each vertex (segment) a color (line number) such that no two adjacent vertices will have the same color (two segments are not overlapping on the same line).

The variation with the constraints could be described as [List Coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring).